# Jquery Live and Proxy with context

Tags: jquery, proxy, live

I'd like to set a context for a function in order to limit its execution to only its inside elements.

```
$('#btn').live('click',function(){
    $.proxy(test(),$(this).closest('div'));
});

function test(){
     //doSomething
}
```

but the context in test() function is not the closest DIV containig my #btn button but the entire page.
Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

$.proxy returns a function.

```
var mytest = function(){
// do something with `this` bound to the jquery collection to be 
// created in the future sometime 
}
$('#btn').live('click',function(){
  // reassign mytest to a new function proxying the context through 
  // a relative jquery collection
  mytest = $.proxy(mytest,$(this).closest('div'));
});
```

This is kind of weird and clumsy, but it should do what you're thinking. There a good chance of running into async issues because the proxy happens on the click. Without knowing the specifics of your problem I don't know if using proxy is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Changing `test()` to `test` doesn't seem to make a difference, strange how that's not working -- but after reading the comments on the jQuery page for `.proxy` -- it seems it's plagued with problems and inconsistencies. I would use something along these lines:

### HTML

```
<div>hello</div>
```

### jQuery

```
function test()
{
  alert($(this).html()); // Will alert hello
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    test.call($('div').get(0)); // I use .get() so only the DOM object is passed.
                                // That makes it more consistent with how jQuery 
                               // passes objects to .each, etc.
})
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/u8x22/

Comment: Would the downvoter explain their reasons? [Encouraging people to explain down-votes
](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes/2373#2373)

Comment: Downvoter was probably disagreeing (rightly) with the statement that .proxy is plagued with problems and inconsistencies. Personally I've had no trouble with it.